# Why when I draw feature on the map Select function is fired?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I create the functionality of selection and drawing on the map.

Here is how I create functionality of selection:

```
var SelectFeature = /*@__PURE__*/(function (Select) {
    function SelectFeature() {

        Select.call(this, {
            condition: ol.events.condition.click
        });

        this.on = Select.prototype.on; 
        this.on('select', function (e) {
            debugger;

            var feature = e.selected[0];
            var center = ol.extent.getCenter(feature.values_.geometry.getExtent());
            //attach popup dynamically
            document.getElementById("popupFeat-content").querySelector("input").value = feature.values_.attributes.Description;
            map.getOverlayById("popupFeat").setPosition(center);
            editableFeature = feature.values_.attributes;
            editableFeatureObject = feature;
        });

    }

    $("#featureEditButton").click(function () {
        initFeatureEditor();
    });


    if (Select) SelectFeature.__proto__ = Select;
    SelectFeature.prototype = Object.create(Select && Select.prototype);
    SelectFeature.prototype.constructor = Select;

    return SelectFeature;
}(ol.interaction.Select));
```

The SelectFeature class is addes to map interactions in map defenition:

```
    map = new ol.Map({
        interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([
            new SelectFeature()
        ]),
        layers: layers,
        target: 'map',
        view: view,
        overlays: [overlay]
    });
```

Here is how I create functionality of selection:

```
function handleMapDrawing() {

    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector()
    });

    var val = $(this).data("value");

    var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: vector.getSource(),
        type: val
    });

    map.addInteraction(draw);
}
```

And handleMapDrawing is fired when shape is selected in DOM:

```
    document.querySelector("#popupShapes ul li a").addEventListener('click', handleMapDrawing, false);
```

But after the shape is selected in the DOM when I make click on the map SelectFeature class fired.

My question is how to prevent SelectFeature to be fired when I draw features?

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical problem of interaction collision or overlap. Usually the way of handling is when a new interaction is activated, the interactions that were in active state and that collides with the new interaction are deactivated.

In your case, when the user click on a shape for drawing you should remove select interaction from map. And in case the selection is by default active, you should add it again to the map when user stop drawing.

You can use `ol.Map` `addInteraction` and `removeInteraction`, to achieve the activation/deactivation.

In OL you might also play with the order of the interaction in the interactions collection of the map (they are executed in reverse order), and with stopping the propagation of the event. But I think the other solution is simpler.